# App Service integrated with Azure key vault - configuration inside an array

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have an API that is installed inside an App Service in Azure, made in .Net Core 3.1.
It is integrated properly with Azure key vault, where we store our secrets.
But there are some sensitive settings inside our appsettings.json that I'd like to store as secrets inside Key vault, and this is quite easy to achieve by setting the key with the path of the configuration, such as:

settings-someSetting-key

But the thing is that my settings are inside an array, something like this:

```
{
"tenantSettings":[{
        "tenantId": 1,
        "repositories": [{
            "name": "repo1",
            "connectionString": "cs"
            },
            {
            "name": "repo2",
            "connectionString": "cs"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "tenantId": 2,
        "repositories": [{
            "name": "repo3",
            "connectionString": "cs"
            },
            {
            "name": "repo4",
            "connectionString": "cs"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

So when I store the path of the configuration in order to match the secret with the setting, this is not working well, and I'm also not sure how I would do it.

Let's say I want to resolve repo1 connection string, what whould be the path?

tenantSettings--repositories[0]--connectionString?

I'm unable to make this work, has anyone ever face the same situation?

Comment: Path to what configuration? Is that blob what you're storing in an Azure Key Vault secret? What's processing the configuration file and replacing content? More information is needed, including code samples of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

@Health on startup I "plug" azure key vault:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Key vault not configured");

            string keyVaultReloadIntervalParameter = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_RELOADINTERVAL");

            TimeSpan? reloadInterval = null;
            int reloadIntervalValue = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(keyVaultReloadIntervalParameter, out reloadIntervalValue) && reloadIntervalValue > 0)
            {
                reloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(reloadIntervalValue);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
            {
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
                {
                    Client = keyVaultClient,
                    Vault = keyVaultEndpoint,
                    ReloadInterval = reloadInterval,
                    Manager = new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager()
                });
            }
```

On ConfigureServices, I read configuration settings to strongly typed representation:

services.Configure(this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings)));

Then I inject ApplicationSettings on controller and do something like this:

applicationSettings.TenantSettings.First(t => t.TenantId == 1).Repositories.First(r => r.Name == "repo2");

With the key vault setup and configuring secrets on key vault, settings are automatically loaded from key vault into this strong typed representation.

The thing is that the name of the secret is based on the index of the array on the configuration:

tenantSettings--0--repositories--0--connectionString

But on my experience matching stuff by index soon or later may cause problems, let's suppose someone adds a new setting on the top of the array. Then all vault secrets are mismatched... So I was wondering if theres is some way of matching by some field instead of the index, something like this:

tenantSettings:tenantId=1:repositories:name=repo1:connectionString

But no success, is there any way to achieve this?